# Comment se nomment les mots de type Xo-Y ?

Tags: terminologie

Socio-démocrate.

Socialo-communiste.

Anarcho-syndicaliste.

Trotsko-léniniste.

Lénino-trotskiste.

Crypto-communiste.

Judéo-chrétien.

Il ne s'agit pas de rayer la mention inutile, ni de trouver l'intrus, mais de trouver le nom du seul point commun entre tous ces mots : la manière de les former en accollant deux mots (possiblement opposés) en insérant un 'o' entre les deux.

Comment: Désolé pour le prosaïsme, j'ai ajouté le tag approprié sans le couper en deux ;-)

Comment: Merci Stéphano-Gimenez.

Comment: Et pourtant *socio-démocrate* me semble bien un intrus ! Je sais bien que parfois on le trouve dans la presse mais le terme consacré est *social-démocrate*. Les noms composés avec socio- en premier terme se réfère en principe à *sociologie* et pas à *socialisme*.

Comment: Merci Lo-re. (Comme on dit, il y a deux types de comique, le comique de répétition et le comique de répétition.)

Comment: Hummm... Je pensais trouver des éléments de réponse dans le définition de [gréco-romain](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/greco), mais c'est plutôt décevant.

Comment: Ne pas oublier les cas comme *sino-indien* ou *américano-canadien* qui semblent indiquer que l'on ne fait pas qu'ajouter `-o` au nom mais qu'il peut être transformé selon certaines circonstances…

Comment: Plus rare en anglais mais je viens de demander quand même: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52156

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je n'ai pas trouvé de mot correspondant à la composition exacte, mais j'ai quand même un début d'explication.

Les mots donnés en exemple sont des mots composés où le suffixe `-o` est une désinence indiquant une coupe dans le premier mot.

Comment: Hmm pareil j'avais pas trouvé mieux que "mot composé". On pourrait peut-être les rebaptiser des mo-composés, juste pour faire bonne mesure (et rendre le néologisme autologique).

Comment: @subtenante : Une aussi bonne réponse, ça se propose =)